# Pure ldap query to search useraccountcontrol with DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD flag set

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to use `ldapsearch` command to search for accounts with `DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD` flag set:

[image]

Since LDAP query syntax does not support binary AND op, what should I use on `userAccountControl` property?

I can't use `Get-AdUser` PowerShell commandlet, I need an LDAP query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP does support binary AND operation, e.g

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536))
```